# Error: "[SC] StartService FAILED 1053" while starting a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, worker

I created a worker service in vs2019, but met error "[SC] StartService FAILED 1053".

[image]

Let me first talk about how I did it.

1, Create a worker service project

[image]

[image]

2, Publish the project

[image]

3, Run cmd.exe as Administrator

[image]

4, Create windows service "testworker" and start it

```
sc Create testworker BinPath="c:\Users\zxi.BS\source\repos\WorkerService1\WorkerService1\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\WorkerService1.exe"
sc start testworker
```

Then i met this error. The exe runs well if i run it directly.
[image]

Why did i get this error:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently running into this issue. But I'm sure in your case, what you are missing is the Nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`. You must then add `UseWindowsService()` to your `HostBuilder`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services)
                => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); });
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2496

Answer (score 0):

Error 1053 is raised because the application you have created is not a true Windows Service. It's not sufficient to extend the BackgroundService class to create a service — work with [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase) instead.

[This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) outlines the approach to take.